# Why `gradle` is executing `ant.replaceregexp` in every subproject?

Tags: java, gradle, ant

I have a java gradle project with this structure:

```
EarApp
|
\---> WarA/trunk
|     |
|     |- build.gradle
|     ...<src and config>
|
\---> WarB/trunk
|     |
|     |- build.gradle
|     ...<src and config>
|
\---> WarC/trunk
|     |
|     |- build.gradle
|     ...<src and config>
|
|- build.gradle
|- settings.gradle
```

My `settings.gradle` is:

```
include "WarA"
include "WarB"
include "WarC"

project(":WarA").projectDir          = file("WarA/trunk")
project(":WarB").projectDir          = file("WarB/trunk")
project(":WarC").projectDir          = file("WarC/trunk")
```

Every `build.gradle` in subprojects contains:

```
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.*
def getSvnRevision(){
    ISVNOptions options = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultOptions(true);
    SVNClientManager clientManager = SVNClientManager.newInstance(options);
    SVNStatusClient statusClient = clientManager.getStatusClient();
    SVNStatus status = statusClient.doStatus(projectDir, false);
    SVNRevision revision = status.getRevision();
    return revision.getNumber();
}


def replaceTokens() {
    ant.replaceregexp(
      file:  "./src/main/resources/messages/text.properties",
        match:   "application.revision=(.*)",
        replace: "application.revision=rev_" + getSvnRevision(),
        byline:  "true"
    )
}


war {
  replaceTokens() // Update rev number
  baseName = nome

  from('config') {
    include 'ibm-web-ext.xml'
    into 'WEB-INF'

    manifest {
      attributes("Application-Name": baseName,
                 "Implementation-Version": versione + 'rev_' + getSvnRevision())
    }
  }
}
```

When executing `gradle -p WarA/trunk war` or `gradle WarA:war` the WarA.war is built correctly but I'm expecting that only the `./src/main/resources/messages/text.properties` of WarA is being updated by *ant*.

Instead I get that every subproject get the `./src/main/resources/messages/text.properties` file updated.

What am I missing?

Comment: If you have a multi-project build, then you should probably use `./gradlew WarA:war` to run a subproject task.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: does not change the result :-(

Comment: What is the console output of that Gradle invocation?

Comment: Because it's run in _configuration_ and since all projects are included, all `build.gradle` files will be parsed and configured.

Comment: @Opal I was thinking that `replaceTokens()` is *executed* only inside `war`. Can you give me an example that points me to the solution?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth --info output it's about 200 lines. Which part is needed?

Comment: Everything that is not an action is executed during initialization or configuration. `war` block is just a configuration so everything will be executed during configuration phase.What you can try is to invoke replaceTokens in `doFirst` closure or use `filter` closure where filtering will be done.

Comment: @sgargel, see (here)[https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:copying_files].

Comment: Thank @Opal! found also https://discuss.gradle.org/t/what-difference-between-configuration-setting-and-dofirst-dolast/23406

Comment: Yup, that's the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving `replaceTokens()` inside a `doFirst{}` will do the trick.

```
war {
  doFirst{
    replaceTokens() // Update rev number
  }
  baseName = nome

  from('config') {
    include 'ibm-web-ext.xml'
    into 'WEB-INF'

    manifest {
      attributes("Application-Name": baseName,
                 "Implementation-Version": versione + 'rev_' + getSvnRevision())
    }
  }
}
```

Reference here: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/what-difference-between-configuration-setting-and-dofirst-dolast/23406